# To test the result of a code change, do I always need to ReBuild the whole thing?

Tags: c++, qt, compilation, qt-creator, compiler-optimization

Working with **Qt Creator 5.7.0 MinGW 32bit on 64bit Windows** and for the first time, I set up and ran a c++ open source **application**. I succeeded in downloading their code, configuring it and Build/Run the project as **Debug**.

One thing I noticed that it **takes between 10 to 15 mins to compile** or Build. So let's say I changed a line of code and I want to test the result: In VS I can Run without the need to ReBuild everything. Do I have this option in Qt or I am missing some additional configuration?

[**Becoming a developer**](https://github.com/LibreCAD/LibreCAD/wiki/Becoming-a-developer) Guide states:
"*You can improve build speed by adding `-j` to the make arguments*"
and "*Using `-j3` on a quad core i5 builds in a little under 3 minutes with clang.*" So I did and used -j3.

[**Installing LibreCAD from source on Windows**](http://librecad.org/cms/home/from-source/windows.html) states:
"*Remove the shadow build from both the debug version and the release version by un-checking the Shadow Build checkbox.*" Which I also did.

Nothing in the application uses or requires internet (build/run - all local). I am on Windows 10 Pro x64-based Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6500 CPU 3.20GHz. 16 GB RAM and my Cpu Utilization hits an average of 80% while building.

I would appreciate any suggestions for a fix. Please and thanks

Comment: I don't think that you need to rebuild everything. Normally the first build on a project will take some time, but successive builds should be fast: Only the changed files should be recompiled and the object files will be linked together again.

Comment: It does not look like doing so. Even if I did not change anything, it still takes 10 to 15 mins to compile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If LibreCAD uses qmake, then unfortunately the builds won't be very quick since recursive make isn't very quick.

If LibreCAD uses cmake, then you should use ninja output from cmake, and then the builds will be as quick as possible.

Comment: This is how my Project Settings page looks like: https://postimg.org/image/i9ltyvdkb/ I assume it is qmake then?

Comment: Make sure that cmake project files aren't available: if they are, they should be preferred. Other than that, using the Visual Studio compiler might be a bit faster; you'd need to test that. Unfortunately, mingw has always had a feel of a step child on Windows. It works, but it doesn't work as well as it could, it seems. You might be better off doing the development on OS X or Linux, and occasionally testing it on Windows.

Comment: [**LibreCAD team**](https://github.com/LibreCAD/LibreCAD/issues/696) says they "_don't think anyone is opposed to supporting msvc;_" .. and somewhere else "_You have to be your own hero to build on Visual Studio_". However, I tried to build with VS and it was a pain. How can I make sure that cmake files are not available? And do you think it is worth it at this point and for the long run to adapt OSX/Linux and use that environment? For me I think yes, I don't want to wait 15 mins for every line change..

Comment: If there's a `CMakeLists.txt` file, then the project supports cmake. Otherwise you have an option of writing your own based on the `.pro` files. Even on Unix you might want to use cmake+ninja to have sub-second build times. On Windows the *only* way to proceed is cmake+ninja+visual studio compiler **or** generate .vsproj files and build under visual studio itself.

Comment: There is no `CMakeLists.txt`. Looks like a lot of work to me :( I think I will go with a virtual box and try compiling the whole thing on a linux OP since they don't support Visual Studio and I found it very hard.. kind of lost right now